# Converting iptables rules to ufw rules

Tags: networking

I need converting iptables rules to ufw rules. my iptables don't seem to work properly so I want add these rules to the ufw instead.  can any help with this ?

```
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/minute --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/minute --limit-burst 1 -j LOG -- log-prefix PING-DROP:
-A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Does UFW actually support rules for icmp? the man page doesn't mention it

Comment: I added it to iptables and I tried restarting it but it gave an error "Failed to restart iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found."

Comment: iptables is not a service. Edit your question and show us your commands and responses.